# error: exec plugin: invalid apiVersion "client.authentication.k8s.io/v1alpha1" in kubectl

Tags: kubectl

I have a kube config to a kubernetes cluster that used to work. I guess after I upgraded the docker desktop, even simple

```
kubectl version
```

will give me this error:

```
error: exec plugin: invalid apiVersion "client.authentication.k8s.io/v1alpha1"
```

Comment: Is it possible that the target kubernetes cluster got upgraded to a newer version?
client.authentication.k8s.io/v1alpha1 got removed in v1.24 (see: [changelog](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/CHANGELOG/CHANGELOG-1.24.md))

You may try to update your ~/.kube/config file with the "k8s.io/client-go/pkg/apis/clientauthentication/v1beta1" (see: [commit](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/108616/commits/5b690b44d08807c6434a421b0041ef685482d337)) or if you have other option to list available api-versions on the cluster (kubectl api-versions | grep authentication)

Comment: yes, my server version is v1.21.12. Once I upgraded the docker desktop, the kubectl client version becomes v1.24.0, which will not support "k8s.io/client-go/pkg/apis/clientauthentication/v1beta1" anymore. When I changed from v1beta1 to v1 in the config, I encountered a different error message like below:
"error: interactiveMode must be specified for <...> to use exec authentication plugin"